# Automatic HTML page generation when new member signup

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am doing a website in which for each member, I want to generate a html page based on the informations this person gave when he/ she signed up (age, city, profile pic, mail, etc.)

**Here is the approach I want to take:**

=> Create a function that:

1. create a new html file
2. Prepare the HTML code based on some HTML barebone code and the data gave by the member (which are the parameters of the function)
3. add this HTML inside the new html file, and save it

=> Add this function in the SignUp function, taking the member data as parameters.

**My question: what are the best ways to do that, using Javascript? (No react, and hopefully, no Jquery)?** My solution might be a little bit complicated and maybe there are easier ways to do that?

Comment: You dont need to create a new html file each time. Just use some templating library and add the users data to it once they sign up. You should also have a loop at https://stackoverflow.com/help as the above question is too broad/opinion based for SO

Comment: Thats a great advice ! Can you give me an example of templating library? I understand your remark about the broad question but I didnt see any ways to make it more specific ... and could not find any answers on the internet

Comment: Not only you don't need to, but you must not! Nobody creates one physical HTML file per user. Definitely create one template with variables ({name}, {age}, {address} etc) and inject your user object in it. Just look up "templating engines".

Comment: @nolw38 just google javascript (or any other language) temple engine

Comment: I updated my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577282/all-members-pages-generated-with-mustache-have-the-same-data-informations-of-a-s

Answer (score 2):

You should learn PHP and use database to generate a dynamic page.
You can learn PHP from https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Creating a new html file is up to you but I don't recommend it...
You should create a PHP file that displays data from form submission .... Store that data in a database (like mysql).

To use firebase with PHP here is a tutorial
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php-firebase-integration/#:~:text=Actually%2C%20Firebase%20provides%20a%20PHP,server%20like%20MySQL%20and%20others.

You can use other languages too like Node Js , etc. But PHP is most common in doing such tasks.

Comment: "You should learn PHP" is just your opinion. My opinion about PHP is that it's completely outdated and uses a web approach from the 90's. I would say "You should learn Node.js and Pug", but somebody else will immediately tell me the same thing I just told you. That's why opinion-based questions are off-topic

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm almost sure that PHP was made for what OP is looking for...

Comment: Oh, it will work, definitely. I'm not saying it won't work. I'm saying I find it very outdated and there are much more modern approaches. It was made for what OP is looking for... in 1994.

Comment: Since your comments are rather opinion-based, I invite you to continue the debate in chat :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a new HTML page for this. It can be done with a single web page. as you mentioned in the question you are looking for javascript solution, so i would like to suggest you to go with the Node.js and mongoDB. Here are the steps

- First you have to setup a Node.js project which is combined with the mongoDB as the Database.
- Then setup the front end with HTML and retrieve the data from the Node.js server you previously created

if You are interrested here is a sample project which i was created with Node.js

https://github.com/bathicodes/School

Set up your project like this and try to retrieve data from it. you only have to pass the member id to the server and it will provide the information of that member

hope this will help

cheers